# Steam wont open Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, steam

When I click the steam icon, nothing happens.

Here are the errors I am getting.

```
steam
 ILocalize::AddFile() failed to load file "public/steambootstrapper_english.txt".
 [2015-11-17 21:16:08] Startup - updater built Nov 25 2013 18:07:05
 libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
 libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
 SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
 X Error of failed request: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
```

Comment: This is for 14.04 not 15.04, I couldn't use that post.

Comment: If probably provide similar errors, but what is the output when your try running `steam` from terminal? Also what hardware/setup are you using?

Comment: Here is the hardware/setup:ASUS M5A99FX PRO R2.0 ATX AM3+,    AMD BOX AMD FX-8350 BLACK ED,     ASUS STRIX GTX960 OC 4GB PCIE